# Итерация по списку словарей

Tags: python, list, словари

Имеется список словарей:

```
data = [
{ 'county' : u'Россия', 'city' : u'Моска', 'street' : '' },
{ 'county' : u'Украина', 'city' : u'Киев', 'street' : 'улица' },
{ 'county' : u'Украина', 'city' : u'Киев', 'street' : 'улица2' },
{ 'county' : u'США', 'city' : u'Нью Йорк', 'street' : '7 street'}
]
```

Необходимо сгруппировать, где  `country` и `сity` в словарях совпадают, и получить такой результат:

```
output_data = [
{ 'county' : u'Россия', 'city' : u'Моска', 'street' : '' },
[ { 'county' : u'Украина', 'city' : u'Киев', 'street' : 'улица' }, { 'county' : u'Украина', 'city' : u'Киев', 'street' : 'улица2' }, ],    
{ 'county' : u'США', 'city' : u'Нью Йорк', 'street' : '7 street'}
]
```

Нужна помощь с логикой - как пройтись и сформировать такой массив? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    {'county': u'Россия', 'city': u'Моска', 'street': u''},
    {'county': u'Украина', 'city': u'Киев', 'street': u'улица'},
    {'county': u'США', 'city': u'Нью Йорк', 'street': u'7 street'},
    {'county': u'Украина', 'city': u'Киев', 'street': u'улица2'},
]

groped_data = groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['county']), key=lambda x: [x['county'], x['city']])

def one_or_list(group):
    group_list = list(group[1])
    if len(group_list) == 1:
        return group_list[0]
    return group_list

output_data = map(one_or_list, groped_data)
```